# How can I repair this sewer cap?

Tags: repair, sewer

My home was built in 1959.  The clean out cap in the basement is 2.5" ID but it doesn't have threads.  It has 2 nubs (now it only has one) opposite each other that fit into two notches in the pipe.  I'm assuming you place it and turn to close it.  I found it today laying on the concrete floor, one nub is missing and the whole thing looks pretty corroded.  Can I replace the cap, I've been looking online and don't see any that look like mine, just threaded ones.

Comment: Is it brass? Only place I've seen those used is in fire systems. See http://www.firehosedirect.com/brass-pin-lug-2-1-2-nh-cap-with-chain/ Best bet is to take the cap to your local plumbing supply shop and see if they can get you a replacement. Using a threaded one may mean a lot of work because you have to change the fitting the plug goes into.

Comment: A photo might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If the pipe itself is in good enough shape, you could just use a compression cleanout plug (sometimes called a mechanical cleanout plug) or a pressure testing plug:

[image]
[image]

There are quite a few different styles of these, but almost all of them work by compressing and expanding a rubber gasket inside the pipe. 2.5" might be hard to find at the big box stores, but they are available numerous places online. The main consideration would be finding one that would seat deep enough into the pipe that it would be beyond the notches for the old cap.